# What weights to use for fermenting sauerkraut?

Tags: fermentation, cabbage, german-cuisine

I am new to making sauerkraut. I do know the right ingredients for making sauerkraut, based on searching on Google.

My question is what equipment should I use to weight the sauerkraut below the brine?

I am using a [Fidos jar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001BMYH0) as a container. If I were rich, I would buy a fermenting crock that comes with stone weights, see for example [this crock](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009VJ4C1E). However, since I am not rich, are there stone weights that I can buy?

My current idea is to use ceramic pie weights, but I have never owned any of these before. Would they be sufficiently heavy to weight the sauerkraut down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Penn State Extension](http://extension.psu.edu/food/preservation/news/2012/sauerkraut) recommends:

> Cover with a plate weighted down with jars filled with water or cover
>   with a large food grade plastic bag filled with salt water (6
>   tablespoons salt per gallon of water.)

Comment: This works if I have a large jar, but my jars are pretty small, with a diameter of 3.5 inches.

Comment: Zip bags come in many sizes...

Answer (score 2):

I can't see why not, pie weights should be fine.  The ceramic weights used in large kraut crocks are unglazed ceramic as are the pie weights.  I would place the weights in a plastic zip bag though, to make sure they don't drift downward, maybe even filling the bag with the brine as well.  Afterward, you could always bake the pie weights to sterilize them between uses too.

Comment: The bag of brine is all you actually need.

Answer (score 2):

Get a set of ceramic weights that fit a 1 liter Fido jar.

https://www.etsy.com/listing/182083359/fermentation-weights-for-1-liter-fido-or

(disclaimer: this is my own product)

Comment: This seems like a good solution. Why did someone give a downvote to this answer?

Comment: Solicitation is generally not allowed unless disclosed and relevant to the question.  This is relevant but I think slightly disingenuous.

Comment: I'm going to assume good intentions here, and just add a disclaimer. It was already pretty obvious that this is Leslie's product, and this is also directly relevant to the question. This is exactly the kind of rare case when we *do* allow linking to your own products. (The disclaimer does need to be there, but I'm not really worried about a rash of jar-weight spam developing here.)

Comment: I agree with Jefromi. The Internet has trained many people to have a negative reaction to any form of self-promotion. Here, we are trying to be better than that and not throw out the baby with the bathwater. So, no matter how it "feels" to see a self-promoting link, if objective evaluation shows that it is relevant to the post, I prefer to let it stay, as our rules prescribe.

Comment: aww, "this item and shop are currently unavailable"

Answer (score 2):

A quick tip: whichever way you weight your kraut, add a piece of outer cabbage leaf (make sure all your veg is organic, not sprayed) under the weights to hold all the bits of kraut under the brine level. It gives you a good wallop of the right bacteria too!

Answer (score 1):

I use [these glass weights](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LOVZVBC), there are quite a few varieties available but the basic idea behind them is the same: they almost completely fill the opening of a Mason jar or other jar which has the same diameter opening (many do). The stone weights in a dedicated fermentation crock do the same job, minimizing the kraut's contact with the air, but the glass weight is one piece instead of two so it's a little harder to get them in and out of the jar than it is with a stone weight like the one Leslie linked to. There are versions for either standard-mouth or wide-mouth jars.

Answer (score 1):

I use the book Making Sauerkraut and pickled vegetables at home. In the book it states to use a water and acid-proof stone such as granite. Limestone or marble will dissolve in carbonic acid. It also states that a board that is either birch or beech are traditionally used for this purpose. Do not use pine or fir, because their strong odors can be transferred to the vegetables. If you use a mason jar or a big gallon jar you will need to cut the weight in half to get it inside the jar. Only fill the jar to about 75% capacity with the vegetables or cabbage, add your stones or boards and if using boards a bag with the salt water solution on top. Making sure that the brine solution is at least an inch above all. Finally after sealing the top I use a rubber grommet in the lid and attach a fermentation lock (the same one I use for fermenting wine) this in turns allows no air to make contact with the fermenting goods, and thus prevents the mold or kahm yeast from forming.

Answer (score -1):

Although weights are highly recommended, I have successfully made cabbage saurkraut without weights. When not using weights you have to make sure you pack down the cabbage nicely, the juices drawn from the cabbage should almost fill the jar. leaving very little air in the jar. Everyday you will have to pack down the cabbage as some of the cabbage bit would be floating and may cause mold formation. This works for me for cabbage and beets.

Comment: "Packing down daily" means opening the jar daily which means you are much more prone to mold because you are not maintaing an anaerobic environment. ...so, not a good plan/method.