# Do I really need fermentation weights for making sauerkraut?

Tags: fermentation

I am reading about fermentation weights, and some sites seem to say I need some, and some others say I don't. It seems so this site, has a consensus that I need one. [Eg](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34584/what-weights-to-use-for-fermenting-sauerkraut). I have set some sauerkraut without weights to ferment today in a glass jar, would it be safe to eat? (been less than a day till now)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need them, but they are helpful.  The issue is that any product above the surface of the liquid has a good chance of developing mold.  The weights keep the product submerged.  You can do the same with a "homemade" weight like a small plate.  I have successfully made kraut with no weights at all.  Just make sure your veg. is below the surface of the liquid.

Comment: And if you do develop mold, it'll be obvious.